# Optimizing COUNT(*) query with 4 MM relations and larger table

Tags: mysql, optimization

I am struggling (again) with the table from this question: [how to optimize this query (4 mm tables involved)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555561/how-to-optimize-this-query-4-mm-tables-involved)

---

It is one main table `product_table` which has four MM relations via the lookup tables `mm1` to `mm4`. The lookup tables have the fields `uid_local` containing  the uid of the `product_table` and `uid_foreign` containing the uid of the categories by which the result gets filtered.

After Quassnois suggestion from the above mentioned question which improved the performance the query looks like this:

```
SELECT
COUNT(*)
FROM
product_table
WHERE
(product_table.partner_id = 0 OR product_table.partner_id = 15) AND
EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM mm1 WHERE mm1.uid_local = product_table.uid AND mm1.uid_foreign IN (10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 53)) AND
EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM mm2 WHERE mm2.uid_local = product_table.uid AND mm2.uid_foreign IN (7, 8, 9)) AND
EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM mm3 WHERE mm3.uid_local = product_table.uid AND mm3.uid_foreign IN (51 ,52)) AND
EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM mm4 WHERE mm4.uid_local = product_table.uid AND mm4.uid_foreign IN (15, 16, 17, 18, 19))
```

This returns somewhat around 10.000 rows as `COUNT(*)` but it takes > 0.5 seconds for the query to execute. This is too slow.

`EXPLAIN` looks like this:

```
id  select_type         table           type  possible_keys           key         key_len   ref       rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY             product_table   ref   NewIndex                NewIndex    4         const     9430    Using where
5   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  mm1             ref   uid_local,uid_foreign   uid_local   4         mm1.uid   5       Using where
4   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  mm2             ref   uid_local,uid_foreign   uid_local   4         mm2.uid   2       Using where
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  mm3             ref   uid_local,uid_foreign   uid_local   4         mm3.uid   3       Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  mm4             ref   uid_local,uid_foreign   uid_local   4         mm4.uid   6       Using where
```

If I change the `product_table.partner_id = 0` to something that returns less rows e. g. a few hundred or so the query is very fast (0.015 sec).

So the problem is that the `COUNT(*)` query is very fast if it needs to count only a few rows (100 - 200) but very slow on counting a larger result set (> 10.000 rows).

Any ideas on how to fix this?

---

A few facts:

- the mm tables have indexes on `uid_local` and `uid_foreign`
- The `product_table` has a indexed PK and there is another index on `partner_id`
- The `product_table` table contains around 30.000 rows

---

**EDIT**

The `IN` clauses are *not* fixed, the query could instead of `IN (7, 8, 9)` look like `IN (7, 9)` or other combination of numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use materialized views for the EXISTS parts of your query. This way, you could fold the `IN` statements into a single query. Then you just need to create an index on `uid` and the query should take almost no time anymore:

```
SELECT
COUNT(*)
FROM
product_table
WHERE
(product_table.partner_id = 0 OR product_table.partner_id = 15) AND
EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM vmm1 WHERE vmm1.uid_local = product_table.uid) AND
EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM vmm2 WHERE vmm2.uid_local = product_table.uid) AND
EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM vmm3 WHERE vmm3.uid_local = product_table.uid) AND
EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM vmm4 WHERE vmm4.uid_local = product_table.uid)
```

The drawback: If you change the mm-tables a lot, the view will need to be updated and that will make the changes to those tables slower.

Comment: What are materialized views? Is the query then still able to take parameters? The user selects the values for the IN clause via a web frontend.

Comment: From your example, I gathered that the IN clauses are fix. If they can change, then this doesn't work.

Comment: A materialized views is a view that gets copied into a dynamic table. The contents of that table will change when you change rows in the underlying tables.

Comment: I clarified the example, but thank you for your suggestion and the explanation, I never heard about materialized views before. Would have been nice to use them, but it does not work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [FORCE INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html) in the mysql manual. if you have 10k rows in your M2M table that match, the optimizer might have decided that scanning the table is better than consulting the index, but in your case, probably not.

Comment: But EXPLAIN output indicates that all indexes are used, or did I read it wrong?